# Why is a singular noun, 'war', used in 'war was inevitable'?

Tags: articles, singular-vs-plural, countability

In the 2nd explanation of the word ['thesis' in the Cambridge Dictionary online](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/thesis), an example sentence goes as 'their main thesis was that war was inevitable'.

Why does it use a singular noun 'war' alone? Shouldn't it use 'a/the war'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The word "war" can be used as both uncountable (large scale conflict) and countable (a particular conflict). In this case the author has chosen the uncountable sense.  It would not have made much difference, in this case, if the author had chosen to use the countable "a war".